# Install VirtualBox on remote machine through RemoteDesktop

Tags: remote-desktop, virtualbox

How can I install VirtualBox on a remote server through RemoteDesktop without being disconnected when the network is set up for VirtualBox?

Can I install it and somehow set a parameter to set up the networking at reboot rather than during the installation?

Answer (score 2):

The RDP connection should come back shortly after the network disconnects, so you will just have to reconnect, I don't see the problem, your desktop session will remain open. Actually if the blackout is as quick as it should, RD will probbaly reconnect for you.

If you want anyway you can also install Virtualbox as an unattended installation, as said here on the [virtualbox manua](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch02.html)l following [Microsoft's instructions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb684783.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for the link. I have tried through RDP and while it should come back, it doesn't for some reason.